# Вопрос по display:inline-block

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="block">
            <div class="avatar">
                <img src="http://iswc2008.semanticweb.org/wp-content/uploads/images/John_Giannandrea-big.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id egestas augue. Nam nec ante egestas, mattis justo rutrum, dapibus erat.
                </div>
            </div>
```

Есть три блока, которые должны быть в одном ряду, а внутри блока картинка и текст должны подчиняться правилу `inline-block`.
Но они не подчиняются, как можете увидеть на [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p1xhcxw3/)
Почему так? И почему содержимое выходит за рамки блока? Почему оно не отображается вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас изображение у которого итак по-умолчанию `display: inline-block` обернуто в `div` - блочный элемент и для текста еще и     `white-space: nowrap;` задан, не переносится текст и вылазит за рамки.

```css
#main {
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: 5%;
    padding: 1%;
}

#main .marquee {
    margin-top: 3%;
   white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

#main .block {
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
}

.block img {
    width: 10%;
}
.block .description {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
    width: 20%;
        white-space: initial;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
        <div class="marquee">
            <div class="block">
            
                <img src="http://iswc2008.semanticweb.org/wp-content/uploads/images/John_Giannandrea-big.jpg">
                
                <div class="description">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id egestas augue. Nam nec ante egestas, mattis justo rutrum, dapibus erat.
                </div>
            </div>
   
    </div>
```